# How to navigate firstViewController to secondViewController without click anybutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I need to know how to navigate from firstViewController to the           secondViewController after 5 seconds. How to define the time to move  automatically, without clicking any button 
i am new in iOS development. i have written this code but getting error. please help. Thanks in advance!

```
  // firstViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "secondViewController.h"//This import is not necessary
#import "firstViewController.h"

@interface firstViewController : UIViewController
  @property (strong, nonatomic) SecondViewController *secondViewController; //This instance is not necessary
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self performSelector:@selector(loadingNextView)withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0f];
}

- (void)loadingNextView
{
  secondViewController = [[secondViewController alloc] init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @yash try my code its worked for me and hope its work for you also

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(yourMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:)

and later use `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Example:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(goToSecondController) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

- (void)goToSecondController {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueInYourStoryboard" sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try my code maybe its helped
if you are using .xib then use initWithNibName otherwise init

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(push) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

- (void)push
{
    secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `UIStoryBoard` then create a segue from first to second. And just execute `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`

If not then, don't worry. Just use `dispatch_after` and write your push code over there. It will execute after specific time.

No need to take `NSTimer` or `performSelector:afterDelay:` you can safely do it with `dispatch_after`.